# Can one retrieve full Row Count as well return partial result

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to simplify and cut down on round trip time for my RestApi. A user will query for a list of all Addresses which lets say are in Zip Code 90017. As i dont want to send down to the App possibly 1000 + records i would like to query and see how many records meet the criteria, if its less the lets say 100 return all records if not return the first 100 as well as the nbr of total records so client app can page thru result.

Comment: Sounds like you know what you want to do. Have you researched how to return the top X records? Have you researched how to return the count of records in a result set?

Comment: Yes, i have figured out both but its separate queries and i am trying to see if i can get this done in a single one

Comment: Please share all the code you wrote and specifically what part of it is not producing what you want.

Comment: You are missing the point, my code does what it needs to do but i am looking for a idea or solution which possibly can do this in a single query so what i have is irrelevent

Comment: A common technique is to create a stored procedure that either returns a row count in an `output` parameter and a result set with the desired rows or [multiple result sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-multiple-result-sets?view=sql-server-2017) where one supplies the row count and another has the desired rows. Or just select the rows you want and add a column that is a subquery returning the total numbers of rows. (Yes, in each row.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for two resultsets?

If so, you can do this:

```
-- return top 100 rows max ( returns all if less than 100 ) --
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM dbo.{your_table_name} WHERE Zipcode = '90017';

-- return record count for zip queried --
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS ZipCount FROM dbo.{your_table_name} WHERE Zipcode = '90017';
```

Or, if you want a single resultset, you can do:

```
SELECT TOP 100 
    avail.ZipCount, ZipInfo.*
FROM dbo.{your_table_name} ZipInfo
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT COUNT( * ) AS ZipCount FROM dbo.{your_table_name} WHERE Zipcode = ZipInfo.Zipcode
) AS avail
WHERE ZipInfo.Zipcode = '90017';
```

Note that the available records count is repeated for each row when using the CROSS APPLY. Also, this method takes longer than selecting the count on its own.

You may be tempted to try:

```
SELECT TOP 100 
    ZipInfo.*
    , ( SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM dbo.{your_table_name} WHERE Zipcode = ZipInfo.Zipcode ) AS RowsAvail
FROM dbo.{your_table_name} ZipInfo
WHERE Zipcode = '90017';
```

However, this consumes more resources than the CROSS APPLY as it's executed with each row--best to avoid it. Use CROSS APPLY instead.

As @HABO's comment mentions you **should** add an ORDER BY to your resultset.

Comment: Brilliant! But `top` without `order by` is oft frowned upon.

Comment: Easily added to the query.

Comment: I tested the cross apply with order by and the time it takes compared to 2 queries is neglect-able.

Comment: Nice. The order by will help you have a good idea of what data to expect back. In your case, it may be moot, but there you go, lol.